# I have a current US visa and legally changed my date of birth in my home country. Can I amend my US visa to reflect this change?

Tags: visas, passports, f1-visas, pakistan

I'm from Pakistan and am currently studying in the United States with an F-1 visa. My parents and I were recently able to prove in Pakistani court that the date of birth on my Pakistani passport and ID documents is wrong. We were therefore able to legally change my date of birth and I have received a new and amended passport. I know I will have to apply for a new F-1 visa, but I'm worried that my previous visa will be considered "fraudulent" due to the wrong age of birth. Is this the case and should I contact a lawyer? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a corrected birth cert?

Comment: Yes, I do. All of my documents have been corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I'm worried that my previous visa will be considered "fraudulent" due to the wrong age of birth

Unlikely you'll have any issue, if the new date of birth is what is in **all** your documents (including US ones like your Social Security Card if applicable, or driver's license), your school issues you with a new I-20 with the correct DOB and you come with **both** the court order and your original birth certificate.

You will just need to explain the reason when asked about

For an exact guidance, please contact your school's International Student Office (you will need to contact them anyway to get a new I-20, so better ask all the questions you have in mind)